# Issue with SQLite gem when installing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Error installing sqlite3, failed to build native gem extension.

Running on Windows 10.

Following a codeacademy [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHgXELONyTQ), I successfully installed Ruby on Rails (ruby version : 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32) (rails version : 5.1.7). Running 'bundle install' popped up with an error saying I needed to download SQlite.

No problem, I go to the SQLite website and download sqlite3. Re-running 'bundle install', I get an error saying :

'An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.'

Following the suggestion, I run this command and get the following error:

'sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first. Could not create Makefile..'

I have download sqlite3 from the website, there is no sqlite3.h file in the folders. My google and SO searches have been fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the steps here:

`https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b`

Github thread - https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/224#issuecomment-482612096

Comment: I am using windows 10, not linux.

Comment: oops. have modified the answer and posted the latest reference & fix to this issue. check it out

Comment: I checked out the thread and followed the steps without success. Check out my comment here as to why it failed - https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/224#issuecomment-482809063https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/224#issuecomment-482809063

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Gemfile** and **replace** `gem'sqlite3'` to `gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'`